# AngularJS Directive for valid number and range

Tags: angularjs, validation

I currently have a angularJS directive to validate a number. What it does now is limit the input to only numbers with 2 decimals. I now have a new requirement that the value cannot be over 50,000. How would I add this to the existing code? I have tried several solutions with no success.

```
(function () {
"use strict";
configAppDirective.directive('validNumber', function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }

            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                    var val = '';
                }
                var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
                var decimalCheck = clean.split('.');

                if (!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
                    decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0, 2);
                    clean = decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
                }

                if (val !== clean) {
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }

               // this doesnt work, only gives an alert
                if (val > 50000) {
                    alert('Fee amount cannot be greater than $50,000');
                    ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                    ngModelCtrl.$render();
                }

                return clean;
            });

            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
  }());
```

Comment: Is this an `input[number]` ?  Can you just do `<input valid-number max="50000">`

Comment: You might edit your question and add the things you tried, so you can avoid potentially unnecessary questions like the one above.

Comment: the directive only works when input type="text"

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, see the code here:

```
configAppDirective.directive('validNumber', ['toastr', function (toastr) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: {
            "id": "@id",
            "placeholder": "@placeholder",
            "class": "@cssclass",
            ngModel: '='
        },
        template: '<input required="required" type="text" class="{{class}}" id="{{id}}" ng-model="ngModel" placeholder="{{placeholder}}">',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                return;
            }
            scope.$watch('ngModel', function (newValue, oldValue) {
                if (newValue) {
                    var clean = newValue.toString().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
                    var decimalCheck = clean.split('.');
                    if (!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
                        decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0, 2);
                        clean = decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
                    }
                    if (parseInt(newValue) > 50000) {
                        toastr.info('Number can not be more than 50000.');
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(oldValue);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    } else {
                        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                        ngModelCtrl.$render();
                    }
                }
            });

            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```